# Avoiding instanceof with OOP

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

```
class Entity {
    // various fields and methods
}

class MobileEntity extends Entity {
    // various fields and methods
}

interface Consumer {
    public void consume(final Consumable c);
}

interface Consumable {
    public void onConsume(final Consumer c);
}

class Player extends MobileEntity implements Consumer {
    // Override methods, etc
    // Can consume
}

class Npc extends MobileEntity {
    // Cannot consume anything
}

class Food implements Consumable {
    public void onConsume(final Consumer c) {
        if (c instanceof Player) {
            healPlayer();
            removeFood(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for putting all of the code first, but I figured it'd be easier for me to explain, and for you to understand if you saw it. This is for a game I'm developing. The problem I'm having is how to deal with a Consumable (be it Food or Drink) without using the ***instanceof*** operator. I would like to avoid setting the concrete class **Player** in the Food class (because there could end up being hundreds of different types of Food), but there are exceptions to the contract in each case (which indicates a problem).

Not all Entity implementations will have a *health* field. They might, but if so, I would need to mark certain ones as "attackable", and then have a test

```
void applyDamage(int damage) {
    if (attackable) {
        health -= damage;
    }
}
```

Which introduces new problems, due to hard-coding behaviour (an indicator to introduce a new class)

I've heard of possibly using the Visitor pattern in similar thread, but I don't think it applies in the current situation.

Comment: The reason I'm passing the Consumer to the Consumable, is because different Consumable objects may need to access different aspects of the Consumer. For example, food would increase/decrease health, a potion might apply a unique effect to the player, drinking a beer might make them dizzy, etc. All things that would need to be defined by the Consumable(Food, Potion, Beer, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Player implements Consumer, the onConsume method in Food should just call the consume() method on the the Consumer. In this case, the Player's version of consume would do the right job. instanceof is not only bad but would fail when the objects are decorated.

Comment: The reason I'm passing the Consumer to the Consumable, is because different Consumable objects may need to access different aspects of the Consumer. For example, food would increase/decrease health, a potion might apply a unique effect to the player, drinking a beer might make them dizzy, etc. All things that would need to be defined by the Consumable(Food, Potion, Beer, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Your Consumer has a consume() method and Player is a Consumer so why not pass the Consumable to the Consumer?  On the other hand, it seems like Player, Npc, and Food are all data models so you might want to keep any business logic (such as increasing health or removing food) out of all your models.  In this case you would need a separate set of classes that know what to do when Food is consumed by a Player.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have the logic backwards - the consumable should be passed to the consumer, and the consumable should have methods that the consumer can call, OR all consumers should implement all possible methods that the consumable can call on them, and do the right thing, which might be nothing.